# Horror film about an escaped serial killer trying to save his girlfriend

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

This is a horror and road trip film about a serial killer who escapes from prison. He learns of a plot by two others to kill his girlfriend by luring her to a remote cabin, and he attempts to travel to this location to prevent his girlfriend from being killed.

This is a fairly recent film (last 4 or 5 years I think). Can anyone identify this film? I'm pretty sure this is a U.S. film, but is possibly Canadian. The scene near the end where the girlfriend has been successfully lured to a cabin is in a snowy location. The escaped serial killer has to navigate around at least one police road block during his travels.

The fact that the killer is trying to save his girlfriend is a twist that is unknown until near the end of the film. I think the audience is expected to believe that the escaped killer is on the run for some nefarious reason, possibly to kill his girlfriend himself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [A Horrible Way to Die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Horrible_Way_to_Die) from 2010.

> In rural Missouri, serial killer Garrick Turrell (AJ Bowen) escapes from police custody and immediately resumes taking the lives of strangers whilst searching for his ex-girlfriend, Sarah. Meanwhile, having met at group therapy for recovering alcoholics, Sarah (Amy Seimetz) and Kevin (Joe Swanberg) begin to develop a tentative relationship. As the body count builds, Turrell makes his way to Sarah's new location just as she seems to be getting her life in order.

Eventually, Sarah winds up in a cabin in the snow and realizes that Garrick is really trying to *save* her from the guys who worship him and want her dead. Here's the trailer: